# Does scrapy automatic retry when hit a exception?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy project finished just now, and I found log say:

```
INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/exception_count': 197,
     'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseFailed': 7,
     'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 190,
     'downloader/request_bytes': 2765511,
     'downloader/request_count': 8616,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 8616,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 107541395,
     'downloader/response_count': 8419,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 8052,
     'downloader/response_status_count/301': 144,
     'downloader/response_status_count/302': 223,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 24, 13, 35, 38, 955000),
     'item_scraped_count': 7861,
     'log_count/ERROR': 4,
     'log_count/INFO': 7918,
     'request_depth_max': 20,
     'response_received_count': 8052,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 8616,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 8616,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 8616,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 8616,
     'spider_exceptions/TypeError': 4,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 24, 12, 45, 5, 812000)}
```

I wonder that does scrapy retry when it get `ResponseFailed` and `ResponseNeverReceived` or other exceptions?,because the result did not match what I thought.There should be nearly 30 thousand items for crawl, but it only crawl 8616.This was the second time I ran this project.First time, it only get 7000 items.And by query the database I see total 9035 unique items, which means first time and second time both crawl some items the other did not see.Why did this  happen?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem until a couple of hours ago. The thing is the Request object default behavior is to filter identical request.
To change that you need to set the 'dont_filter' arguments of your Request to True

This settings is use to avoid crawling loop, but if you're in an horizontal crawl,  (many urls but each one only at the surface as the 30k urls suggest it) this shouldn't be an issue

Look for dont_filter here :

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=dont_filter#request-objects